# chrome-error: в HTML выдает ошибку

Tags: css, html5

Не удалось считать сопоставление источника для chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:" выдает ошибку при запуске в Visual Studio Code

Comment: Запуске чего? Сформулируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы было бы хоть на миллиметр понятнее.